# libusb returning empty packets on isochronous transfer in Android 4.4.2

Tags: android, libusb, uvc

I am trying to write a native app which uses libuvc and libusb to interface UVC cameras. This app seems to work well on Android 5.0 and upwards. On Android 4.4 the libusb call for transfer gets empty data all the time and hence camera never returns a capture.

Has anyone faced a similar issue with libusb on Android?

Usage: I am trying to adapt the libuvc(which internally calls libusb) example code to work from an Android Native app. You can find the libuvc usage example [here](https://ken.tossell.net/libuvc/doc/). It is a basic example of how to fetch frames.

Comment: I have no idea acutally, but including a code sample so that more knowledgable can reproduce this more easily might help to get better answers.

Comment: @g_bor Just added the example